# Spring Boot with context path excluding statics

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am using Spring Boot as an API and Angular as the frontend for my Application. I build with Maven and so configured the frontend-maven-plugin so it copies all the Angular dist folder into the final jar when building.

What I would like to have is all of my controllers' mapping to have a prefix like '/api' so it becomes '/api/users', but also that my static resources mappings stay what they are, like only '/sign-up' instead of '/api/sign-up'.

So I searched for the `server.context-path` and `server.servlet-path` properties but none of them worked. Anyone can help me please ?

Comment: Well, just use the appropriate value in your RequestMapping, GetMapping, etc. annotations.

Comment: I not completely sure about this but I think you can create a base controller class with `RequestMapping("/api")` and any class extending from it will have `/api` already added to it.

Comment: @JBNizet I know I could do it this way but the goal is tat I would like to centralize this logic so that if the base controllers URL changes then it is applied to all controllers.

Comment: @Zeronex I just tried this but it did not work, thank you anyway

Comment: Use a constant: `@RequestMapping(API_URL + "/foo")`. But IMHO, if the URL ever changes, which is unlikely, changing the request mappings will be the easiest thing to do.

Comment: Changing the context-path will change all URLs, I don't think there is any way around it, considering, that it will change it on Tomcat level. Depending on the architecture you could take into consideration whether to have the static resources on Spring Boot. They could be on a separate server, that is just for static files, like Nginx, and Spring Boot could only contain the json api.

Answer (score 1):

```java
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configurePathMatch(PathMatchConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.addPathPrefix("/api",
            HandlerTypePredicate.forAnnotation(RestController.class)
                .and(HandlerTypePredicate.forBasePackage("com.company.api")));
    }
}
```

Comment: Answer without comments is useless. Please explain your code